# Get max date (last date sale) column against each item no?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following SQL Query which return result

[image: result img]

of `itemno` and `no of total quantity` sale.I want `itemdescripton` column against each item no as well.`ITEMDESC#` column in table `invitems`.

SQL QUERY :

```
 select INITEMS.ITEMNO,(COUNT(INITEMS.ITEMNO)*COUNT(INITEMS.QTY)) 'Item 
 Sale',INITEMS.ITEMDESC#1 from InvItems INITEMS
INNER JOIN InvHdr HDR ON INITEMS.INVNO=HDR.INVNO
WHERE INITEMS.TYPE='3'
GROUP BY INITEMS.ITEMNO,INITEMS.ITEMDESC#1
```

I want `max date (last date item sale)` column in result.`Date` column in `InvHdr` table against each `InvNo`

Comment: Sample data and expected output would be better to help!

Comment: i want another column add in result which contains `item description` of each item no and i`itemdescription` column is in `InvItems` table

Comment: but it contradict with `I have use INITEMS.ITEMDESC# and in group by also use INITEMS.ITEMDESC# but it return more columns`

Comment: @don yes that I understand but if you provide the script of sample data in the question then it would btter try on your data!

Comment: @Squirrel but it give  me more result due to group by if i not use group by then error occur must use group by,

Comment: oh you mean rows. This means you must have some `ITEMNO` with more than one `ITEMDESC` value in your table. Check your table

Comment: by the way your question title says `Get max date`, but your query has nothing on date at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explain in the earlier comments, your query does not works because you have different `ITEMDESC` for the same `ITEMNO`

This you "gives" you the result that you want

```
select INITEMS.ITEMNO,
       MAX(INITEMS.ITEMDESC#1) AS 'ITEMDESC',
       (COUNT(INITEMS.ITEMNO)*COUNT(INITEMS.QTY)) 'Item Sale'
FROM   InvItems INITEMS
INNER JOIN InvHdr HDR ON INITEMS.INVNO = HDR.INVNO
WHERE INITEMS.TYPE = '3'
GROUP BY INITEMS.ITEMNO
```

But you must check why there are such as in your data. You can list out those ITEMNO that is of such case

```
SELECT ITEMNO
FROM   InvItems 
GROUP BY ITEMNO
HAVING MAX(ITEMDESC#1) <> MIN(ITEMDESC#1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are working with an SQL Server version higher than 2005 (which is a pretty safe assumption these days), you can use the [`over`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) clause with aggregating functions, thus potentially eliminating the need for the `group by` clause (that is potentially since `group by` will return distinct results for each value (or set of values) that exists in the `group by` clause - so you might also need to use `distinct`:

```
SELECT initems.itemno,
       COUNT(initems.itemno) OVER (PARTITION BY initems.itemno)
       * SUM(initems.qty) OVER (PARTITION BY initems.itemno)
FROM InvItems AS initems
WHERE initems.type = '3'
```

Comment: You can easily add `max` of any column with the group by clause, since it is an aggregating function, or just use that with the `over` clause as I've shown in my answer.

Comment: but i use your query it give me huge record about `4200` but i want just `275` record which is `distinct itemno`

Comment: Already adressed that in my answer: "so you might also need to use distinct:"